# Extending an Ember model with a custom variable

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-model, ember-rails

My Ember App has a Section Model.
It has a 'name' field and I've extended it with a 'summary_of_changes' field.
When I attempt to get the length of the name field all is good. 
Attempts to get the length of the 'summary_of_changes' field is generating an error (see below) and driving me crazy.

This works:

```
# coffeescript
App.SectionEditController = Ember.ObjectController.
  isReadyToSave: (->
    @get('model.name').length > 3
  ).property('model.name'),
```

But this (almost identical code) doesn't

```
App.SectionEditController = Ember.ObjectController.
    editMode: true,
  isReadyToSave: (->
    @get('model.summary_of_changes').length > 3
  ).property('model.summary_of_changes'),
```

..and produces the following error.

```
‘Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined’
```

By way of further background, my store is a Rails API and I have a model for a 'Section' of a business plan.The model contains: name, details but not 'summary_of_changes'.

When I save changes I also want to submit a summary_of_changes string that in the controller I save into a save_comment along with other save_comments about changes to that section.

In essence I want to add summary_of_changes as a temporary field that saves with the model but that is cleared to blank again once the model is saved.

In Ember I added this field to my model:

```
App.Section = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  details: DS.attr('string')
  sort_order: DS.attr('number')
  plan: DS.belongsTo('plan')
  summary_of_changes: DS.attr('string')
```

I have modal code (see my example jsbin http://jsbin.com/hekaga/1/edit?css,js,output) which refers to the 'summary_of_changes' field and I am able to bind the field so that changes to the modal live change the same named field in the main section template.

I don't understand why even though I can see the summary_of_changes field on the template as well as even drop it into a related modal and have the two bound together that I can't then ask it it's length as I am able to do with any other field on the model.

Versions:
I'm running the latest ember-rails (0.15.0) which includes Ember 1.5.11 and Ember-data 1.0.0.beta.5

Comment: `@get('model.summary_of_changes.length') > 3`

Comment: also you don't need to prefix it with model, the controller proxies the model, also in javascript we camelCase stuff ^^

Comment: Thanks! Im just testing this now. Hey submit it as an answer and I can give you upvotes etc.

Comment: patsy: For my understanding, can you explain why @get('model.summary_of_changes').length returns undefined?

Comment: It is a computed property,you ll need to use the get and set methods in order to access/manipulate it.

Comment: Evolve: its because model.summary_of_changes is returning undefined, and you're trying to call length on that. Recommend taking a look at [this post](http://eviltrout.com/2013/06/15/ember-vs-angular.html) particularly the bit on getters and setters.

Comment: @ridget he's calling .length on an ember computed property, it's not about what it returns, get('model.summary_of_changes') returns an object

Comment: What had me so stumped is that @get('model.name').length > 3 worked but @get('model.summary_of_changes').length > 3 didn't. Any clues why?

Comment: Could you setup a [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com) with your model/controller would be easier to explain based off of it

Comment: @PatsyIssa forgive my ignorance on this one, but he was asking why the @get('model.summary_of_changes').length returns ‘Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined’

As far as Im aware @get('model.summary_of_changes') is returning undefined, unless he's somehow explicitly set it as an object? Can you point me in the right direction if I have the wrong end of the stick on this?

Comment: @PatsyIssa your recommendation '@get('model.summary_of_changes.length') > 3' has fixed my main issue. The jsbin I've done is probably as close as I can get, with the modal, modal contents and the main view there's a fair few moving parts to be worth reproducing it further than I have above.

Comment: I tried many things but would not have thought to string more code within the get statement. How much further can I push this. Could have I for example defined a method lessThan(number) and used that too? eg @get('model.summary_of_changes.length.lessThan(3)'). Have any links to help me understand this better. Can't beleive how long I spent looking for the answer elsewhere due to the not-so-useful error messages.

Comment: [the docs help](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_lt). [join me in the chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63494/ember-js) for further discussion/help, too many comments here